# Firebase and react-native integration

Tags: firebase, react-native

I have been reading about the integration of firebase analytics and react-native. However I haven't found almost nothing official documentation about this. So, I was wondering if anyone can provide me an official source to know how can I implement firebase analytics on my react-native app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the API cause you are not developing natively:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start?hl=es

Comment: Thanks I will try this!